# How to do a real-time human face detection by iPhone camera？

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift

This is the Swift language version.(source adress:[Swift Version.](http://www.open-open.com/lib/view/open1438438855910.html))

And this is my codee.Anybody can help me find the reason that it didn't work?

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>

@interface ViewController ()<AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate>{
AVCaptureSession *captureSession;
AVCaptureDevice *captureDevice;
AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer *previewLayer;
UIImage *resultImage;
BOOL isStart;


}

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
isStart = NO;
[self isStartTrue];
captureSession = [[AVCaptureSession alloc]init];
captureDevice = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];

captureSession.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetLow;
NSArray *devices = [[NSArray alloc]init];
devices = [AVCaptureDevice devices];
for (AVCaptureDevice *device in devices) {
    if ([device hasMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo]) {
        if (device.position == AVCaptureDevicePositionFront) {
            captureDevice = device;
            if (captureDevice != nil) {
                NSLog(@"Capture Device found");
                [self beginSession];
            }
        }
    }
}
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}


-(void) isStartTrue {
isStart = YES;
}

-(void)beginSession {
AVCaptureDeviceInput *captureDeviceInput = [[AVCaptureDeviceInput alloc]initWithDevice:captureDevice error:nil];
[captureSession addInput:captureDeviceInput];
AVCaptureVideoDataOutput *output = [[AVCaptureVideoDataOutput alloc]init];
dispatch_queue_t cameraQueue;
cameraQueue = dispatch_queue_create("cameraQueue", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL);
[output setSampleBufferDelegate:self queue:cameraQueue];
NSDictionary *videoSettings = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInt:kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA],kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey, nil];
output.videoSettings = videoSettings;
[captureSession addOutput:output];
previewLayer = [[AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer alloc]initWithSession:captureSession];
previewLayer.videoGravity = @"AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspect";
previewLayer.frame = self.view.bounds;
[self.view.layer addSublayer:previewLayer];
[captureSession startRunning];

}


-(void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput didOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection{

if (isStart) {

    resultImage = [[UIImage alloc] init];
    resultImage = [self sampleBufferToImage:sampleBuffer];

    CIContext *context = [CIContext contextWithOptions:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:kCIContextUseSoftwareRenderer]];
    CIDetector *detector = [CIDetector detectorOfType:CIDetectorTypeFace context:context options:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:CIDetectorAccuracyHigh forKey:CIDetectorAccuracy]];
    CIImage *ciImage = [[CIImage alloc]init];
    ciImage = [CIImage imageWithCGImage:resultImage.CGImage];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        previewIV.image = resultImage;
    });
    NSArray *results = [detector featuresInImage:ciImage options:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:6] forKey:CIDetectorImageOrientation]];
    for (CIFaceFeature *face in results) {
        UIImage *faceImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:[context createCGImage:ciImage fromRect:face.bounds] scale:1.0 orientation:UIImageOrientationRight];
        NSLog(@"     ====%@", NSStringFromCGRect(face.bounds));


    }

}
}


-(UIImage *)sampleBufferToImage:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer{

CVImageBufferRef imageBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer);

void * baseAddress = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddressOfPlane(imageBuffer, 0);
size_t bytesPerRow = CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRow(imageBuffer);
size_t width = CVPixelBufferGetWidth(imageBuffer);
size_t height = CVPixelBufferGetHeight(imageBuffer);
CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
int bitsPerCompornent = 8;
CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(baseAddress, width, height, bitsPerCompornent, bytesPerRow, colorSpace, (kCGBitmapByteOrder32Little | kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst));
CGImageRef imageRef = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context);
UIImage *result = [[UIImage alloc]initWithCGImage:imageRef scale:1.0 orientation:UIImageOrientationRight];
return result;

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
[captureSession stopRunning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

This is the whole code for this detection viewcontroller.

You can copy this and import the AVdoundation.framework and coremedia.framework.

Comment: in what way does it not work?  does it crash, do you get errors, you need to be a bit more specific than just asking people to make your code 'work'

Comment: OK, as Mr.Russell said.I append some more detail info of the situation.It didn't crash and didn't get any errors.It just didn't correctly detect my face and then NSLog the info for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at your previewIV, you will find it is a empty image.

So I change your sampleBufferToImage method as blow, and it works.

```
-(UIImage *)sampleBufferToImage:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer{

    CVImageBufferRef imageBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer);
    CIImage *ciImage = [CIImage imageWithCVPixelBuffer:imageBuffer];
    CIContext *temporaryContext = [CIContext contextWithOptions:nil];
    CGImageRef videoImage = [temporaryContext
                             createCGImage:ciImage
                             fromRect:CGRectMake(0, 0,
                                                 CVPixelBufferGetWidth(imageBuffer),
                                                 CVPixelBufferGetHeight(imageBuffer))];
    UIImage *result = [[UIImage alloc] initWithCGImage:videoImage];
    CGImageRelease(videoImage);
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It can catch the camera image after edit my code as you said.I have accepted your answer.Thank you again!